# Choosing best model produced from different algorithms. Metric produced by cross-validation on the train set or metric produced on the test set?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, measurement-error, metric

I know that choosing between models produced by one algorithm with different hyperparameters the metric for choosing the best one should be the cross-validation on train set.

But what about choosing between models that are produced by different algorithm? By which metric should I compare them, the metric produced by cross-validation on the train set or metric produced on the test set? Also why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not on the test set. Model selection is a generalised hyperparameter optimisation and should be done over validation set(s). Imagine all different models embedded in a single model object with the algorithm (and associated hyperparameters) as a hyper parameter.